# Converting Matlab anonymous functions to Scilab inline functions

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, scilab

Most of my Matlab functions can be converted with the `mfile2sci` function to Scilab functions except some functions that contain [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) (for example `f=@(x,y)sin(x)+log(y)`). Is there a way to convert the anonymous functions to Scilab [inline functions](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/deff.html) (for example, for the previous example `deff('[z]=f(x,y)','z=sin(x)+log(y)')`) so that I don't have to change my Matlab functions?

Comment: Scilab now has a `regexp` function. I am wondering if it is possible to extract that pattern out. Something like validMatlabFunctionNanme\s?=\s?@\(someText\) MathematicalExpression...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in its current state the Matlab to Scilab translator `mfile2sci` fails to translate anonymous functions, but this behavior can be improved by the following patch:

https://codereview.scilab.org/#/c/20916/

However, be warned that anonymous function occur most of the time when using "solvers" like `fsolve`, `optim`, ode solvers (e.g. `ode45`, `ode15s`,...), and that statements using these are never translated to working Scilab statements (a warning is given).

Comment: thanks a lot. would you be kind to share the regular expression you have used here?

Comment: Yes, you can find in the code of patched file at https://codereview.scilab.org/#/c/20916/2/scilab/modules/m2sci/macros/kernel/m2sci_syntax.sci